# Pearson correlation for all rows in Data Frames Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, feature-extraction

I have a dataframe in Pandas and its shape is (136, 1445). I try to create correlation(Pearson) matrix for my 136 rows. So in the result, i need  a matrix with size 136x136.

I tried two different ways but i cannot get a results from them or when i  create a 136x136 correlation matrix, i lost the columns name of dataframe.

First,

```
gene_expression = pd.read_csv('padel_all_drug_results_original.csv',dtype='unicode')
gene_expression = gene_expression.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
gene_expression.corr()
```

This gives the column based pearson correlation matrix(1445*1445), and when I try to transpose my dataframe and then try to find correlation, the structure of dataframe is broken (like the columns name is lost or i dont even sure that the correlations are correct or not).

Secondly,

```
distance = lambda column1, column2: pearsonr(column1,column2)[0]
result = gene_expression.apply(lambda col1: gene_expression.apply(lambda col2: distance(col1, col2)))
```

What should i do to calculate 136x136 pearson correlation matrix to do not change the original dataframe ?

Also, I have a 1445 features and some of columns nearly full of zeros. So I dropped that columns because they are noisy columns but have you got another idea to feature redeuction ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the correlation matrix containing pairwise correlation between all rows, you can:

```
gene_expression.T.corr()
```

Using a toy example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, high=100, size=(5, 10)), index=list(string.ascii_lowercase[:5]))
```

with 5 labeled rows and 10 columns:

```
df.info()
Index: 5 entries, a to e
Data columns (total 10 columns):
0    5 non-null int64
1    5 non-null int64
2    5 non-null int64
3    5 non-null int64
4    5 non-null int64
5    5 non-null int64
6    5 non-null int64
7    5 non-null int64
8    5 non-null int64
9    5 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(10)
memory usage: 440.0+ bytes
```

Using

```
df.T.corr()
```

yields

```
          a         b         c         d         e
a  1.000000  0.209460 -0.205302 -0.294427  0.353803
b  0.209460  1.000000 -0.530715 -0.117949  0.775848
c -0.205302 -0.530715  1.000000 -0.245101 -0.344358
d -0.294427 -0.117949 -0.245101  1.000000  0.058302
e  0.353803  0.775848 -0.344358  0.058302  1.000000
```

Comment: I don't why but in my dataframe the column index's are change to the 1,2,3,4....135. 
But in anyway your suggestion is correct , thanks.

Comment: After set_index to the first column of my pandas it fixed.